# How to Insert into SQL Server using ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server

I tried to insert into SQL Server with the below code but it's not working. If I manully given the value instead of ? then it's working fine.

```
app.post("/outwrkwip/insert",(req,res)=>{

    sql.connect(config,function(err){

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request();

        var values = ["MTRT421PV42FOG","11-MAY-22","4249.1","MTBI","16954073"];

        var sqlqry = `INSERT INTO dbo.outworkwip_Tb_KK (Order_Number,prod_Target_Date,Line_No,Order_Type,Batch_Number)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);`                        

        request.query(sqlqry, [values], (err,recordset)=>{           
                
            if(err){                
                console.log(err)
            } else{
                res.send({message : "Successfully Data Inserted"});
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the error message or response you get back? Have you tried wrapping the text/date values in single quotes? If those values are being passed in as-is the SQL would be invalid: `(MTRT421PV42FOG,11-MAY-22,4249.1,MTBI,16954073)` should be `('MTRT421PV42FOG','11-MAY-22',4249.1,'MTBI',16954073)`

Comment: One assumes you're using the Node `mssql` library. Are you certain it supports `?` placeholders? Have you tried using [named parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection) instead?

Comment: after putting                                                                                                                    
var values = ['MTRT421PV42FOG','11-MAY-22','4249.1','MTBI','16954073'];   
 Showing the same errror as below                                                                 
                originalError: [Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error]

Answer (score 0):

below said the code working fine...

```
app.post("/outwrkwip/insert",(req,res)=>{

    sql.connect(config,function(err){

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request();       


        
        request.input('Order_Number', sql.VarChar, 'MTRT421PV42FOG');
        request.input('prod_Target_Date', sql.VarChar, '11-MAY-22');
        request.input('Line_No', sql.VarChar, '4249.1');
        request.input('Order_Type', sql.VarChar, 'MTBI');
        request.input('Batch_Number', sql.VarChar, '16954073');

        let stmt1 =  `INSERT INTO dbo.outworkwip_Tb_KK(Order_Number,prod_Target_Date,Line_No,Order_Type,Batch_Number)  
        VALUES (@Order_Number,@prod_Target_Date,@Line_No,@Order_Type,@Batch_Number);`

        
        request.query(stmt1, (err, results) => {

            if (err) {
              return console.error(err.message);
            }

            res.send({ message : "Successfully Registered"}); 

        });
    });

});
```